# Spring Build Problem - Can't Find Beans Schema

Tags: java, spring, maven-2

I'm using Maven2 and Spring 3, when I run my project in Eclipse everything works fine, but when I use assembly:assembly, the resultant jar throws the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" 
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 4 
in XML document from class path resource [beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception 
is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of 
element 'beans'.
```

my beans file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"> 
    <!-- Beans Here -->
</beans>
```

this file is stored in src/main/resources

my pom.xml has the following dependency for spring:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

any ideas why this is happening? how to fix?

UPDATE:

further probing Google turns out that Spring and Maven don't get on too well with the following in my pom.xml, although no solution is forthcoming:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>org.robert.xclades.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. Using the shade plugin helped, but I had to add an transformer as described in http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html to concat Spring's handler and schema files.

Comment: Thanks, that seems a much nicer way to merge the files!

Comment: Indeed, I've seen this before - I don't know why I didn't look closer before. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

One solution I found that works with Spring 2.5.6 is to include a single Spring jar instead of separate jars.  I'm not sure if there is a signle jar for Spring 3.x.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, it seems, is that there is conflict between each of the different spring.handlers and spring.schemas in the META-INF folders of the various spring dependencies.

The trick I found is to override these by creating these files in src/main/resources/META-INF and copying and pasting the contents of those individual files into these.  Secondly, use the maven-jar-plugin to set the manifest's mainClass; and the maven-shade-plugin, instead of the maven-assembly-plugin. So the updated pom.xml looks like:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>org.robert.xclades.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

So all that is required now is `maven package`.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).